# How to merge columns with colon sign

Tags: linux, bash

I have a tab separated file that looks like this. I need to prepare it so I can import it in R:

```
1      344544     rs30540
2      284783     rs34560
14     384643     rs30567
19     584643     rs31110
Genome_phase,common=1,19,genomes=hg19
11    222643     rs30543
44    544643     rs32345
Genome_phase,common=1,23,genomes=hg19
```

I want to keep only the rows that start with numbers and  drop all others that begin with characters. It is a huge file of a few Gbs. Is there any way to do that in Linux?

Comment: Please make your data readable.

Comment: Thank you I have edited it. Regards

Comment: Cheers. Do all the character lines include 'Genome_phase' and all the other lines don't? If so you could use `grep -v 'Genome' file` to select all lines not containing 'Genome'.

Comment: No the file has character lines with different characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` or `gawk` (depending which you have installed on your Linux version).

```
gawk '/^[0-9]/' file > newfile
```

Since your aim is to read this into R, I suggest you use `fread` from `library(data.table)` as it is fast for large files. In that case you could use the  the ability of `fread` to accept a shell command that preprocesses the file as its input.

```
cmd = paste("gawk /^[0-9]/", filename)
x = fread(cmd = cmd)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the title of the question, I guess you also want to replace `\t` with `:`. Then try the following:

`sed -n '/^[0-9]\+\t/s/\t/:/gp' inputfile.txt`

- `/^[0-9]\+\t/` part finds line that starts with digits followed by a `\t`.
- `s/\t/:/` substitutes `\t` by `:`.
- `g` means global (i.e., substitute *all* `\t`), and `p` means 'print the line'. (We need to explicitly force print since we put option `-n`, i.e., 'silent'.)